# How do you calculate percentage change for token supply?? Is there a need for scaling factor?

Tags: solidity, foundry, math

Is this how you calculate percentage change of new token price? I am not using any oracle.

```
// START_REBASING_SHARE_PRICE is 1e30. 

        uint256 percentChange = (sharesAfter * START_REBASING_SHARE_PRICE) /
            sharesBefore;
        uint256 targetNewSharePrice = currentRebasingSharePrice +
            (delta * START_REBASING_SHARE_PRICE) /
            percentChange;
```